# how to get genome 3 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: unity, launcher, minimize

[image]i dont know that whether i am using unity launcher or any other launcher but it is clear that i have never made any changes in my ubuntu but now i want to get genome 3 in my desktop can any one give me a sequence of commands to get it installed
currently my launcher looks like this
and i am not getting any minimise button for the window[image]

is there any solution for this answer
will reinstalling ubuntu fix the problem
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can install gnome shell from **software center**

Comment: what about the minimize option option then and also when i try to install it through software centre this error appears as shown in my edited answer

Comment: i cant get the answer for minimise option can you explain it a bit better

Comment: try this once... Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 to go to command line session then run **unity --reset** to reset all your Unity related settings. You can then get back to the usual graphical session by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7.

Comment: how to get it done i mean when i press ctrl+alt+f1 scren goes blank

Comment: you are not getting a tty screen? then you can also try running command by pressing ALT + F2

Comment: which command should i run

Comment: **unity --reset**

Comment: `unity --reset` gives you the error "ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated". Use `unity --replace`.

Comment: i have edited my question again as it shows an  other error

Comment: i have used the same command and it shows the error which is been displayed in the screenshot added to my question